# Leetcode doesnt seem to take my answer on Rotate Array

Tags: javascript

This answer is with regards to the question on Rotate Array on leetcode (array-646).
The answer should be `[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]` and when I `console.log(ans)` I get the same thing in vscode. However, when I post it on leetcode it doesn't understand my answer. It keeps saying your answer is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. How do I change it so it understands my answer?

```js
const k = 3;
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var rotate = function (nums, k) {
  var FN = [];
  var LN = [];
  for (i = 0; i < nums.length - k; i++) {
    FN.push(nums[i]);
  }
  console.log("FN:", FN);

  for (j = k; j > 0; j--) {
    LN.push(nums[nums.length - j]);
  }
  console.log("LN:", LN);

  const ans = [].concat(LN, FN);
  console.log(ans);
}
```

Comment: if it doesn't understand your answer, maybe start looking there: what does that site mean when it tells you that? (and don't tell us, find out for yourself, and then find out what needs changing. This isn't something you should need SO's help for). After all: why would it even _run_ your code if it doesn't understand it?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't run anything either - if I add rotate(nums) it logs empty arrays.

Comment: `rotate(nums, 3)` gets me the desired output. Maybe include the description of the Leetcode problem here as well maybe you are missing some minor detail.

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to modify the original array (`nums`)? Copying and pasting the problem description into the question will help clear that up.

Comment: Part of the lesson every coder must learn is: read the requirements very carefully. And then read them again.

Comment: i've modified your code so that rather than returning a new array, it modifies the array it was given. that's why leetcode is rejecting your solution.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you mean [this exercise](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/). The short description is:

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

Note the comments in the template they've provided:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} k
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
 */
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
    
};
```

It sounds like leetcode is expecting you to change the contents of the array that you're given. Instead, you're creating a new array. If you output the array after calling your method, you can see that it's still giving `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, like leetcode is reporting.

```js
const k = 3;
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var rotate = function (nums, k) {
  var FN = [];
  var LN = [];
  for (i = 0; i < nums.length - k; i++) {
    FN.push(nums[i]);
  }
  console.log("FN:", FN);

  for (j = k; j > 0; j--) {
    LN.push(nums[nums.length - j]);
  }
  console.log("LN:", LN);

  const ans = [].concat(LN, FN);
  console.log(ans);
}

rotate(nums, k);
console.log(nums);
```

> How do I change it so it understands my answer?

I'm not sure how much detail you want here: you still want it to be *your* answer, after all. In broad terms, you need to change your function so that it alters the `nums` array that was passed into it, to have the same series of numbers that you have in your `ans` const.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. so you're returning a different array rather than modifying the actual array given to you. I've modified your code to do what leetcode is asking of you. let me know if you have any questions.

```
const k = 3;
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var rotate = function (nums, k) {
  //copy array into new array
  var copy = nums.slice();
  // empty array
  nums.length = 0;
  var FN = [];
  var LN = [];
  for (i = 0; i < copy.length - k; i++) {
    FN.push(copy[i]);
  }

  for (j = k; j > 0; j--) {
    LN.push(copy[copy.length - j]);
  }
  nums.push.apply(nums,LN);
  nums.push.apply(nums, FN);
  return nums;

}
console.log(rotate(nums, k)) //[ 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: I don't think it's expected to return it, or else leetcode wouldn't say the answer is [1, 2, 3, ...]

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to this, finally it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to directly overwrite the `nums` variable, i.e. `nums = rotate(nums, k);`.

Comment: Most likely leetcode specified the `rotate` function signature, and expects the function to change whatever array is passed in. I doubt they expect your code to arbitrarily assign variables.

Comment: Yes, it is also possible. The problem should have clearly stated what to do in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} k
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
 */
```

The third instruction says you should modify the array that was passed into the function. That means the **nums** array.

In your code you are not doing that. You are storing the answer in another array called **ans**. That is why leetcode isn't accepting your answer.

```
  const ans = [].concat(LN, FN);
  console.log(ans);
```

Just be careful about these two things.

1. Read the instructions carefully.
2. Do not change the name of the given function. This will also give an error-message even though your code might work on your machine.